# PHP PDO Size of the database

Tags: php, database, pdo, size

I was wondering how could I get the size of the database in PDO. I was using this before but Im unsure how to convert it to PDO.

```
  function DatabaseSize(){
  $Database = DB_NAZEV;
  mysql_select_db($Database);  
  $q = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS");  
  $size = 0;  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {  
      $size += $row["Data_length"] + $row["Index_length"];  
    }
  return $size;
  }
```

Thank you :)

EDIT: Sorry, that was really unnecessary question...

I managed to get away with :

```
    $Size = 0;
    $Pdo = $this->Pdo;
    $Query = $Pdo->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS");
    $Query->execute();
    $Result = $Query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($Result as $Row){
      $Size += $Row["Data_length"] + $Row["Index_length"];  
      }
    return $Size;
```

Comment: What exactly you are not sure about

Comment: Which would lead me to believe you are unsure of how to do a query in PDO. Just find any tutorial/doc about getting started with PDO and you should have that query running in no-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fairly straight forward, the SHOW statement returns values just as a normal `SELECT` would.

```php
// Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test');

// Execute query
$sth = $dbh->query('SHOW TABLE STATUS');

// Get size from array
$size = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["Data_length"];
```

Comment: @vascowhite Some people tend to downvote when you dare help with questions they think are too straight forward :) Why that'd make it "not useful" I'm not sure about.

Comment: Sometimes I wish it was mandatory to comment if you down vote.

Comment: I read this nearly 3 years later and I aggree. Downvoting should be justified. Like this it just gives it a bad taste. People do not know why. Not funny !